# Where did I go wrong in this putnam question?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

I won't be writing each step explicitly because it takes me forever to write this up in math format.

$$
\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}{{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}+{\sqrt{\ln{(x+3)}}}}\,dx $$

My solving of it went as follows:
$$
\int_2^4 \frac{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}{{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}+{\sqrt{\ln{(x+3)}}}}  \frac{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}}}\,dx=
$$
$$
=\int_2^4 \frac{{\ln{(9-x)}}}{{{\ln{(9-x)}}}+{\sqrt{\ln{(9-x)}\ln{(x+3)}}}}\,dx 
$$

It has at this point been an hour and I won't waste more time to make the equations look pretty.
$$
=\int_2^4\frac{\ln(9-x)}{(\ln(9-x) + \ln(9-x)^{\ln(x+3)/2}}\,dx
$$

Factor out ln(9-x) and cancel and you get

$$
\int_2^4\frac{1}{1+\ln(9-x)^{(\ln(x+3)-2)/2}}\,dx
$$
After a bit more simplifying (bringing down the exponent and multiplying, then moving the 2 out of the integral, then simplifying the remaining $\ln$'s) you get
$$
2\int_2^4\frac{1}{2+\ln\frac{x+3}{9-x}}\,dx
$$
And this is an easy integral because it is directly derived from arctan. I get the antiderivative is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\ln\frac{x+3}{9-x}}\right).
$$
But when I try to use that for the definite integral, I get a negative under the square root, so it must be wrong. Can someone explain where I must've gone wrong? I hope I gave enough information so that you know what I did.

Comment: The formula is so badly written that people will understand a completely different thing.

Comment: @KennyDuran Is the editing right? (Not sure about the anti-derivative). It does not look good - some inner derivatives are missing (beyond other troubles). Try to derivate it to see if you get the integrand.

Comment: The editing is perfect, thank you A.G.. A big problem is that when I derivate the antiderivative, I may get an unsimplified version of the integrand, which could be the same but in a different form. Using a derivative calculator (after I tried myself), I get something that looks very similar, but is not quite right. Here's a picture: http://i1049.photobucket.com/albums/s394/Kasperix/Derivative_zpsnju5binf.png                                                                                                                Also, I don't think this is a duplicate. I'm asking what I did wrong.